# convert -l, -L on C++ linker line to full paths

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies

I have in my make file a list of libraries to link into the executable formatted as follows:

```
LIBRARIES=-L/usr/lib -lmail
```

and I want to use it to fill out a makefile dependency list so that the executable will re-link any time one of the linked libraries changes.
I expect that I will need to translate the linker line into full paths for each library and then specify them as dependencies like so

```
$(EXEC_NAME) : /usr/lib/libmail.so
```

Is there a utility that will translate the search paths and lib names into full paths? or is there a better way to specify the makefile dependencies?

Comment: Do you really change libraries that often (and more importantly, in a way that causes the library to not be compatible)?? I don't think there is any automatic way to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, we have a large project that includes quite a few libraries, most of which are under active development and changing frequently. The interfaces between the libraries are internal only and do change frequently.

Comment: If you build those libs that won't work because those libs may not exist when you run your script from make to find them.

Comment: the libs will exist when the execs are built, our make system already guarantees this.